# Showr for Android

Tags: app, android, widget

### Screenshot

[image: Showr on a Nexus 7]

### About

Put artwork and information at your fingertips, or make your Android device truly personal, with [Showr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr). Showr adds pictures to your **home screen** or **lock screen**: picked from your device's Gallery (or another app), or downloaded from the Internet and automatically updated by your schedule or from an **Atom** or **RSS** feed.

Making it easy to see your **Stack Exchange flair** was one of the motivating uses for this app, so integration with the Stack Exchange API provides a really simple way to add your flair to your home screen. You don't have to copy-and-paste a URL, or find your user ID for each site, like you do with other apps. Showr lets you **pick the site and user** you want to see **from a list**. There's no need to authenticate or use your web browser at all. You can stop it downloading over 3G networks and even treat particular Wi-Fi networks as 3G.

As well as your Stack Exchange flair, Showr also lets you see your build and test status, webcams, comics, photo blogs, weather forecasts, stats from an online gaming service, photos of your family, Tumblr blog, …

#### License

Showr is a free download from Google Play, including all the Stack Exchange functionality.

#### Download

[image: Get it from Google Play]

#### Platform

Showr is available for Android smartphones and tablets running 3.2 Honeycomb or later.

### Contact

Showr is a product of [Shadowburst Software](http://shadowburst.com/). You can add feedback and feature requests here, or for a quicker response, by email to `support` at that domain.